# Ruby 2.4/Rails 5: making a recursive array of hashes, deleting if key is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a class that looks like this that turns a collection into a nested array of hashes:

```
# variable_stack.rb
class VariableStack
  def initialize(document)
    @document = document
  end

  def to_a
    @document.template.stacks.map { |stack| stack_hash(stack) }
  end

  private

  def stack_hash(stack)
    {}.tap do |hash|
      hash['stack_name'] = stack.name.downcase.parameterize.underscore
      hash['direction'] = stack.direction
      hash['boxes'] = stack.boxes.indexed.map do |box|
        box_hash(box)
      end.reverse_if(stack.direction == 'up') # array extensions
    end.delete_if_key_blank(:boxes) # hash extensions
  end

  def box_hash(box)
    {}.tap do |hash|
      hash['box'] = box.name.downcase.parameterize.underscore
      hash['content'] = box.template_variables.indexed.map do |var|
        content_array(var)
      end.join_if_any?
    end.delete_if_key_blank(:content)
  end

  def content_array(var)
    v = @document.template_variables.where(master_id: var.id).first
    return unless v
    if v.text.present?
      v.text
    elsif v.photo_id.present?
      v.image.uploaded_image.url
    else
      ''
    end
  end
end

# array_extensions.rb
class Array
  def join_if_any?
    join("\n") if size.positive?
  end

  def reverse_if(boolean)
    reverse! if boolean
  end
end

# hash_extensions.rb
class Hash
  def delete_if_key_blank(key)
    delete_if { |_, _| key.to_s.blank? }
  end
end
```

This method is supposed to return a hash that looks like this:

```
"stacks": [
{
  "stack_name": "stack1",
  "direction": "down",
  "boxes": [
    {
      "box": "user_information",
      "content": "This is my name.\n\nThis is my phone."
    }
},
{
  "stack_name": "stack2",
  "direction": "up",
  "boxes": [
    {
      "box": "fine_print",
      "content": "This is a test.\n\nYeah yeah."
    }
  ]
}
```

Instead, often the boxes key is null:

```
"stacks": [
{
  "stack_name": "stack1",
  "direction": "down",
  "boxes": null
},
{
  "stack_name": "stack2",
  "direction": "up",
  "boxes": [
    {
      "box": "fine_print",
      "content": "This is a test.\n\nYeah yeah."
    }
  ]
}
```

I suspect it's because I can't "single-line" adding to arrays in Rails 5 (i.e., they're frozen). The `@document.template.stacks` is an ActiveRecord collection.

Why can't I map records in those collections into hashes and add them to arrays like `hash['boxes']`?

**The failing test**

```
APIDocumentV3 Instance methods #stacks has the correct content joined and indexed
 Failure/Error:
   expect(subject.stacks.first['boxes'].first['content'])
     .to include(document.template_variables.first.text)

   expected "\n" to include "#1"
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1 @@
   -#1
```

The presence of `\n` means the join method works, but it shouldn't join if the array is empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reverse_if` returns `nil` if the condition is false. Consider this:

```
[] if false #=> nil
```

You could change it like this:

```
def reverse_if(condition)
  condition ? reverse : self
end
```

`delete_if_key_blank` doesn't look good for me. It never deletes anything.

Disclaimer. I don't think it's a good idea to extend standard library.

Comment: You're right on both accounts, but neither explain why my methods don't collect the right information. I'll attach the failing test.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, you're right. In my test they all have text, though, so none should be removed. It's null even if I replace the bottom `content_array ` method to just return `'test'` or something, so my problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your help here. I've posted an answer with what worked for me, and while your answer did help me get there it doesn't answer the original question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Danil Speransky I solved this issue, although what he wrote doesn't quite cover it.

There were a couple of things going on here and I solved the `nil` arrays with this code:

```
hash['boxes'] = stack.boxes.indexed.map do |box|
    box_hash(box) unless box_hash(box)['content'].blank?
  end.reverse_if(stack.direction == 'up').delete_if_blank?
end
```

That said, I'm almost certain my `.delete_if_blank?` extension to the `Array` class isn't helping at all. It looks like this, FYI:

```
class Array
  def delete_if_blank?
    delete_if(&:blank?)
  end
end
```

I solved it by thowing the `unless box_hash(box)['content'].blank?` condition on the method call. It ain't pretty but it works.